# three non numeric characterts

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to check if a Vb.net string contains at least 3 non white space characters of which at least one non numeric character.

Can anyone help creating the regular expression for it?

> ab c valid
>
> 2c a valid
>
> abc valid
>
> 1 invalid
>
> 123 invalid

I have tried this one

```
^[A-Z]{3}$
```

but It is not working

Comment: I suggest you break it down to two regular expressions and check both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive look-ahead to assure that there is at least one character that is not a digit (in this example A-Z), then require three non-white-space characters (`\S`) separated by zero or more white-space characters (`\s`).

```
(?=.*[A-Z])\S\s*\S\s*\S
```

Comment: You will need to add a `.*` to your lookahead, `(?=.*[A-Z])\S\s*\S\s*\S` otherwise it will only match if the first `\S` is `[A-Z]` anyway +1

Comment: @Guffa will it work if string length can be greater than 3 and if non numeric is not the first character

Comment: @Guffa atleast 3 non white space characters of which atleast one is non numeric character.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Yes, it only requires one character anywhere in the string to match the look-ahead (`[A-Z]` in the example) and that there are three non-whitespace characters anywhere in the string.